# Can I have resizable by mouse views with Cappuccino?

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

Can I have resizable by mouse views with Cappuccino ?

I mean, I need a "iTunes" layout as the layout sample code on their website.
But I wold like to be able to resize the areas with the mouse from the browser in order to customize the UI.

Can I make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CPSplitView to put two mouse resizable views side by side. The divider between them can then be clicked and dragged with the mouse to reallocate space between the two views. This is the equivalent of Cocoa's [NSSplitView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).